How to Call Function Inside .xaml Page From A .blazor Page in MAUI
I want to call a function from a .xaml.cs file from within a .blazor page. The goal is to call it when a specific button is clicked, but I can't find any information on how to accomplish this; the most I've found is communicating from MainLayout.razor, which isn't helpful to me. Having the button be directly inserted into the .xaml file won't work either, because I need it to be inaccessible except under certain conditions determined inside the .blazor page. I tried Application.Current.MainPage, but sadly that does not allow me to reach the function. Any and all help is appreciated!
Ideally, the blazor code would look something like:
<button @onclick="ActivatesXAMLFunction">Activate .xaml Function</button>

@code {
    protected async Task ActivatesXAMLFunction()
    {
        var mainPage = Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Application.Current.MainPage as MainPage;
        if (mainPage == null){  }
        else
        {
            await mainPage.XAMLFunction();
        }
    }
}

which would trigger a function in the MainPage .xaml class:
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public async Task XAMLFunction()
    {
        //XAMLFunction code
    }
}

App.xaml.cs code:
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
    }
}


Could you please include some relevant code to help us understand what you want to achieve?

I use Application.Current.MainPage and can access the function in XAML page.
<button @onclick="ActivatesXAMLFunction">Activate .xaml Function</button>

@code {
public async Task ActivatesXAMLFunction()
{
    NavigationPage mainpage = Application.Current.MainPage as NavigationPage;
    MainPage rootpage = mainpage.RootPage as MainPage;
    await rootpage.XAMLFunction();
}

And in MainPage code-behind,
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public async Task XAMLFunction()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("123");
    }
}

When clicking the Button, the XAMLFunction in MainPage can be invoked.

After solving some other errors in my code that triggered first, this is throwing the error System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' on the await mainPage.XAMLFunction(); line. It seems that mainPage is always assigned to null.

Actually this works on my side (It may because I only use default Blazor template). In order to reproduce this exception, could you please also share more code such as App.xaml.cs and MainPage.xaml or any related info about how to reproduce it.

Updated the blazor function as much as possible, and added App.xaml.cs code.

I think that because you set the MainPage as NavigationPage in App.xaml.cs. I update some changes for ActivatesXAMLFunction. Please have a try.
